# Trying to record a path from xml root, to a specified node

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I want to be able to get the path from the root node of an xml document, to a specified node in the tree. I have a base algorithm right now, but it is not removing the nodes that do not lead to the specified node (I want to find the shortest path from the root to that node).

```
private static List<string> firstPath = new List<string>();
private static XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
private static bool run = true;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    doc.Load("XML doc name");
    foreach(XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes)
    {
        path("Specified node you want the path to", node);
    }
    printPath(firstPath);
}

private static void path(string name, XmlNode node)
{
    foreach(XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        if(childNode.Name == name)
        {
            firstPath.Add(childNode.Name);
            run = false;
        }
        else if(childNode.ChildNodes == null) //last descendant
        {
            firstPath.RemoveAt(firstPath.Count - 1); //remove the most recent
        }
        else
        {
            if (run)
            {
                firstPath.Add(childNode.Name);
                path(name, childNode);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void printPath(List<string> list)
{
    foreach(string str in list)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Example XML doc:

```
<XML_Tree_Name>
<Root Node>
    <Node 1>
        <Node 2/>
        <Node 3/>
    </Node 1>
    <Node 4>
        <Node 5/>
        <Node 6>
            <Node 7/>
        </Node 6>
    </Node 4>
</Root Node>
```

Say I want to get the path from the root to node 7. That path would be `Root, 4, 6, 7`. However, it is not removing the nodes that did not lead to 7, so the path that is recorded is `Root, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`.

How can I properly remove the nodes from the list that do not lead to the desired node?

Comment: Do you actually need to remove the nodes from the tree, or do you just want to get the path?

Comment: @KyleW I do not want to remove anything from the XML document iteself, I want to remove the unnecessary nodes from the list the path is recorded in. These are the nodes that were parsed over, and recorded, but later should be realized that they have no relation to the path of the desired node. Nodes 1, 2, 3 may have been recorded originally, but they should be removed once they program finds that they do not lead to node 7 (in this case the desired node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because all paths add the node to the list.  (The == null will never be true, it will be an empty list.)

In order to greatly simply your code, start at the END and work backwards.

```
var list = new List<XElement>();
var s = @"<RootNode><Node1><Node2/><Node3/></Node1><Node4><Node5/><Node6><Node7/></Node6></Node4></RootNode>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(s);
var finalNode = doc.XPathSelectElement("//Node7");

for(var currentNode = finalNode; currentNode != null; currentNode = currentNode.Parent)
{
    list.Add(currentNode);
}

foreach(var node in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
}
```

Also, you should avoid global-scoped variables, if you don't need them.  Return the list from your function:

```
private static List<XElement> GetPath(...) {...}

static void Main()
{
    var pathList = GetPath(...);
    PrintPath(pathList);
}
```

Comment: It worked with your example, but when I try to load in my own XML file it gives me the error "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1". I am guessing this is because it is the title line of the XML documents, and not an actual node.

Comment: @FyreeW Your example has XML_Tree_Name as an extra node with no end.

Comment: @FyreeW If this helped you, please upvote and accept as answer.

Comment: The tree that i am actually working with has something similar, it is not actually the root node, it is the name of the document. How would I get around this?

Comment: @FyreeW How does it load in your example?  If it works there, it should work in both locations.  If it doesn't work there, I would look at removing the incorrect tag through string manipulation.

Comment: var doc = XDocument.Parse("Document path"); is how I am doing it, but the first line does not have an end because it is not a node. It is the title of the document (<Title>).

Comment: @FyreeW `Parse` is for XML that you have in a string.  `Load` is for loading it from a Stream or file.

Comment: So would I load in the file, and then parse through it, while ignoring the first line?

Comment: @FyreeW First line of what?  `XDocument.Load("<location of file")` will load a file containing XML

Comment: I load the file into a var called file, and then try var doc = XDocument.Parse(file); however it says that it needs a string, not System.XML.Linq.XDocument to string.

Comment: "@FyreeW `Parse` is for XML that you have in a string. `Load` is for loading it from a Stream or file. "